# MVC .NET Core UseStaticFiles OnPrepareResponse not hit for JavaScript files

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, optimization, gzip

I'm trying to set up GZIP for my static files (primarily JavaScript) which have been pre-compressed using Webpack's compression plugin (compression-webpack-plugin).

I have followed this article on serving pre-compressed static files using .NET Core - https://dzone.com/articles/serving-pre-compressed-static-files-in-aspnet-core.

I have the following in my `Startup.Configure` method:

```
var mimeTypeProvider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    OnPrepareResponse = context =>
    {
        var headers = context.Context.Response.Headers;
        var contentType = headers["Content-Type"];

        if (contentType != "application/x-gzip" && !context.File.Name.EndsWith(".gz"))
        {
            return;
        }

        var fileNameToTry = context.File.Name.Substring(0, context.File.Name.Length - 3);

        if (mimeTypeProvider.TryGetContentType(fileNameToTry, out var mimeType))
        {
            headers.Add("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
            headers["Content-Type"] = mimeType;
        }
    }
});
```

This doesn't seem to have helped, my assets are being served without compression. When adding a breakpoint into the `OnPrepareResponse` action method, it is not hit for any JavaScript files. It does get hit for my favicon and my logo image though.

I've also tried this NuGet package - https://github.com/AnderssonPeter/CompressedStaticFiles - which also didn't seem to solve my problem.

Here's a screenshot of my wwwroot folder for reference:

[image]

I'm trying to serve those JS files in the /dist folder using the following references in my _Layout.cshtml view:

```
<script src="~/dist/vendors~main.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="~/dist/main.bundle.js"></script>
```

Finally, here's an example of the headers for vendors~main.bundles.js (taken from Chrome dev tools):

[image]

Any ideas on why this isn't working?

**UPDATE 08/05/2019**

It seems that the static files middleware is conflicting with the Webpack Dev Middleware somehow. If I remove the following lines of code from my Startup Configure method then it works and the breakpoint in `OnPrepareResponse` is hit for all files as expected:

```
app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(new WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions
{
    HotModuleReplacement = true
});
```

Is this a bug or am I just doing something wrong?

Comment: Just a heads up - this looks like an issue with .NET Core. The .NET Core guys are investigating here: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/10076#issuecomment-490581941